# Cleanup malicious code while allowing some HTML (before persisting to DB)

Tags: php, symfony, twig, ckeditor

I have a **Symfony** project where any user can register for an account and then create a `page` with a form that includes a field `content`. I want to allow users to insert some html (like bold text, numbered lists and some other elements), which I have done by using a WYSIWYG-editor, **CKEditor**. I have created a toolbar that only allows the elements I have chosen to be parsed to the database when saving the `page`. I can show the content of this page by using:

```
{{ page.content | raw }}
```

This all works as expected. However, is a user was to copy the post-request, edit in some JS or other HTML and use cURL to send it, this would allow them to insert (harmful) code. **My question is:** how to prevent this from happening?

I have been reading about 'sanitation' or 'purification' to cleanup user input. Something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) could cleanup the output, which I also considered doing by creating a sort of 'whitelist twig filter' for the elements I do allow. Preferably I would cleanup the input before persisting it to the database. I imagine this is a common issue, but I only find solutions on how to cleanup the output, usually by escaping all HTML, which in my case is also not a solution because I do want to allow some HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could purify this in your form type, after the user submits the form with the [HTML Purifier Library](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier) and symfony form events:

```
use HTMLPurifier;
use HTMLPurifier_Config;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $object = $event->getData();

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', ['a', 'b', 'strong', 'ul', 'li', 'p', 'br']);
    $config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', ['_blank']);
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
    $content = $purifier->purify($object->getContent());

    $object->setContent($content);
});
```

So in this example the users content is cleaned up. The `HTML.AllowedElements` defines which elements should not be removed. After that the entity is ready to be persisted to your database without bad html user content.

Comment: Looks promising, I am gonna run some tests.

Comment: Symfony 6.1 you can find a build in solution -> https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-htmlsanitizer-component

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not to manipulate user input. You should validate/reject user input (example: user uploads 10GB of data, or the user starts a div element, but doesn’t end it), but don’t change it. It’s not going anywhere or going to infect anyone by sitting in a database.

When you display the page to the user, that is when you manipulate the data. Like you said, escape your characters: < for <, &amp for &, and &quot for “.

I was recently programming for this, and what I did was use an XML parser (luaexpat). In your case, you have PHP that has an XML parser library.

Run the user input HTML through the XML parser. If any unauthorized elements show up, you can either escape them (<) on output or throw an error instead of the content. It is also good to make sure that the content has valid XML, so a user can’t mess up the rest of the page by not closing an element.

Another idea is to store “version identifiers” of post types. If you decide to add more features/attributes or switch to another encoding (like BBCose), write a note in the database so it will be easier to decode the posts. This is another reason why you should NOT change user input, but rather user output in case you start off by denying images, then you decide to allow it later on.

Also whitelist attributes too. Don’t let someone put JavaScript in an attributes (such as `<div onclick=“MaliciousCode();”>`)

Be sure to look out for SQL injection attacks and HTML injection attacks.